# How to Identify correct URL pattern of SharePoint to get list of items by title from Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, postman

My goal is to get all items or files names at this URL

`https://myOrganization.sharepoint.com/sites/supplierABC/DataSheet/Forms/AllItems.aspx`

I have followed this [link](http://www.ktskumar.com/2017/01/access-sharepoint-online-using-postman/) and I already have client Id and client secret for the SharePoint URL by using them I am able to generate access token successfully. By using generated access token in Authorization (Postman header), I am trying a get request in Postman with URLs:

`https://myOrganization.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test')/items`
`https://myOrganization.sharepoint.com/sites/supplierABC/DataSheet/Forms/AllItem.aspx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test')/items`

My question here is which URL should be used before **_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test')/items** either

1. https://myOrganization.sharepoint.com

   or
2. https://myOrganization.sharepoint.com/sites/supplierABC/DataSheet/Forms/AllItems.aspx (files are present here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your REST URL should be:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + _api/web/lists/getbytitle('test')/items
```

Comment: @Anurag_BEHS Please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you!

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! 
for those who are new bee like me . we can get this _spPageContextInfo from the browser console of our share point url. After pressing f12 in browser -> go to console ->and hit _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl -> you will get the answer.   so complete url will be -> https://myOrganization.sharepoint.com + _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + _api/web/lists/getbytitle('test')/items ...    Thanks  a lot Sohail...

Comment: @Anurag_BEHS Pleasure